# Does spring always require KafkaTemplate?

Tags: spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

question :Does springboot always require to create a bean of type KafkaTemplate?
Details/stacktrace/codebase  below, please tell me what i am doing incorrect . Thank you

1. I have been posting messages to a topic from a spring boot project
2. In order to create callback mechanisms i have used org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer.send(ProducerRecord<K, V>, Callback) in order to send the message and also create a call back
3. the reason i did this way is because listenablefuture when using KafkaTemplate only provides exception on failures( and i wanted to register callbacks as a separate reusable class across all my usecases)
4. however, spring fails to start up when i dont define a bean of type KafkaTemplate with the below error

```
    Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'kafkaTemplate' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/kafka/KafkaAutoConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'kafkaTemplate' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'org.springframework.kafka.core.ProducerFactory' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:800) ~[spring-beans-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:541) ~[spring-beans-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1352) ~[spring-beans-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1195) ~[spring-beans-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:582) ~[spring-beans-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542) ~[spring-beans-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:276) ~[spring-beans-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1380) ~[spring-beans-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory$DependencyObjectProvider.getIfUnique(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:2063) ~[spring-beans-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.kafka.KafkaAnnotationDrivenConfiguration.(KafkaAnnotationDrivenConfiguration.java:90) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.4.12.jar:2.4.12]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:490) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:211) ~[spring-beans-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
        ... 22 common frames omitted
    Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'org.springframework.kafka.core.ProducerFactory' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoMatchingBeanFound(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1790) ~[spring-beans-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1346) ~[spring-beans-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1300) ~[spring-beans-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:887) ~[spring-beans-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:791) ~[spring-beans-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
        ... 40 common frames omitted
```

My Kafka COnfig is below

```
  @Configuration
public class KafkaEventConfig {

    private final KafkaProperties kafkaProperties;

    @Value("${client.id}")
    private String clientId;


    @Value("${topic.movie.name}")
    private String movieTopicName;
    
    @Value("${retry.backoff.ms}")
    private int retryBackoffMilliseconds;

    @Value("${request.timeout.ms}")
    private int requestTimeoutMilliseconds;

    public KafkaEventConfig(KafkaProperties kafkaProperties) {
        this.kafkaProperties = kafkaProperties;
    }

    @Bean
    public ProducerFactory<String, Movie> producerFactory() {
        Map<String, Object> props = kafkaProperties.buildProducerProperties();
        populateCommonProperties(props);
        return new DefaultKafkaProducerFactory<>(props);
    }

    private void populateCommonProperties(Map<String, Object> props) {
        props.put(ProducerConfig.CLIENT_ID_CONFIG, clientId);
        props.put(ProducerConfig.RETRY_BACKOFF_MS_CONFIG, retryBackoffMilliseconds);
        props.put(ProducerConfig.REQUEST_TIMEOUT_MS_CONFIG, requestTimeoutMilliseconds);
    }
    
    @Bean
    public KafkaProducer<String, Movie> movieKafkaProducer() {
        return new KafkaProducer<String, Movie>(producerFactory().getConfigurationProperties());
    }

    @Bean
    public KafkaProducerMonitor kafkaProducerMonitor(KafkaProducer<String, Movie> kafkaProducer,
            MeterRegistry registry) {
        return new KafkaProducerMonitor(kafkaProducer, registry, Tags.of("topic", movieTopicName));
    }
```

My Kafka Callback is below

```
       @Slf4j 
public class KafkaProducerCallBack<K, V> implements Callback {

    private ProducerRecord<K, V> producerRecord;

    public KafkaProducerCallBack(ProducerRecord<K, V> producerRecord) {

        this.producerRecord = producerRecord;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCompletion(RecordMetadata metadata, Exception exception) {
        String topicName= metadata.topic();
        long offset= metadata.offset();
        
        if (exception != null) {

            log.error("Failed to produce message [{}] to topic {} with exception {}", producerRecord, topicName, exception);
        }

        else {

            log.info("Sucessfully published message [{}] to topic {} to offset {}", producerRecord, topicName , offset);
            
        }

    }

}
```

I publish messages like so

```
movieKafkaProducer.send(message, new KafkaProducerCallBack<String, Movie>(message));
```

Please note the moment i add the below lines in KafkaEventConfig everything works fine

```
@Bean
    public KafkaTemplate<String, Movie> movieKafkaTemplate() {
        return new KafkaTemplate<String, Movie>(producerFactory());
    }
```

Comment: No it doesn't, however you are manually configuration parts of Kafka and Spring Boot will also try to do some auto-configuration. If you disable the auto-configuration for Kafka you don't need the `KafkaTemplate`. Or you take benefit of the auto-configuration and use the `KafkaTemplate` (which can be automatically provided by Spring Boot) to send messages instead and simplify your own configuration.

Comment: thank you, that was brilliant..these two worked perfectly.. @EnableConfigurationProperties(KafkaProperties.class)
@SpringBootApplication(exclude=KafkaAutoConfiguration.class)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Additional to the latter that @M.Deinum mentioned:**

Take a look at the `KafkaAutoConfiguration` class:

```java
    @Bean
    @ConditionalOnMissingBean(KafkaTemplate.class)
    public KafkaTemplate<?, ?> kafkaTemplate(ProducerFactory<Object, Object> kafkaProducerFactory,
            ProducerListener<Object, Object> kafkaProducerListener,
            ObjectProvider<RecordMessageConverter> messageConverter) {
        KafkaTemplate<Object, Object> kafkaTemplate = new KafkaTemplate<>(kafkaProducerFactory);
        messageConverter.ifUnique(kafkaTemplate::setMessageConverter);
        kafkaTemplate.setProducerListener(kafkaProducerListener);
        kafkaTemplate.setDefaultTopic(this.properties.getTemplate().getDefaultTopic());
        return kafkaTemplate;
    }
```

Springboot will create a `KafkaTemplate` bean for you if you don't create your own. This auto-configured bean depends on `ProducerFactory<Object, Object>` bean, and because you declared a `ProducerFactory<String, Movie>`. As you could see the type wasn't fit, that's why you got an error.

---

> the reason i did this way is because listenablefuture when using KafkaTemplate only provides exception on failures( and i wanted to register callbacks as a separate reusable class across all my usecases)

Your case, you can still get the advantages of using `KafkaTemplate`. Instead of implementing a `Callback`, you can implement your own `ProducerListener<K, V>` and bind it into your `KafkaTemple`. E.g:

`FullLoggingProducerListener.class`

```java
public class FullLoggingProducerListener<K, V> implements ProducerListener<K, V> {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(ProducerRecord<K, V> record, RecordMetadata recordMetadata) {
        log.info("Successful!");
    }

    @Override
    public void onError(ProducerRecord<K, V> record, @Nullable RecordMetadata recordMetadata, Exception exception) {
        log.error("Error!");
    }
}
```

`YourConfigration.class`

```java
    @Bean
    public KafkaTemplate<?, ?> kafkaTemplate(ProducerFactory<String, Movie> kafkaProducerFactory, ProducerListener<Object, Object> kafkaProducerListener) {
        KafkaTemplate<String, Movie> kafkaTemplate = new KafkaTemplate(kafkaProducerFactory);
        kafkaTemplate.setProducerListener(kafkaProducerListener);
        return kafkaTemplate;
    }
```

Now, everytime you use `KafkaTemplate` to send a record, you'll see the log.

Answer (score 2):

Taking a closer look at your exception stacktrace reveals the issue.

```java
Error creating bean with name 'kafkaTemplate' defined in class path resource
 [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/kafka/KafkaAutoConfiguration.class]: 
Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'kafkaTemplate' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'org.springframework.kafka.core.ProducerFactory' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}
```

The error comes from not being able to apply the Kafka based auto-configuration in Spring Boot. The class `KafkaAutoConfiguration` expects and configures some beans, and backs off if certain ones are found. As you are configuring some of the beans, this will partially backoff and thus fail to auto-configure the Kafka classes.

To fix you can either exclude the `KafkaAutoConfiguration`. You can do this in your `@SpringBootApplication` annotation, like so

```java
@SpringBootApplication(exclude={KafkaAutoConfiguration.class}
```

Or you can utilize the auto-configuration and let Spring Boot do the configuration and you use the provided `KafkaTemplate` or `ProducerFactory` to do what you want.

The latter would simplify your own configuration. I'm know too little of the Kafka auto-configuration and your usecase to provide a more helpful code snippet, but you should be able to figure that out yourself, or just exclude the `KafkaAutoConfiguration` and go with what you have now.